# How do I write series to specific existing column in csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Thank you very much for your time and help.
I have a pandas series named `Lon_count`, now I want to write it to existing column named `stationLon` in a csv file read by `filepath`. I tried

```
filepath_10ormore =  r'path.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath_10ormore)
...
Lon_count.to_csv(filepath_10ormore,float_format="%.4f",columns= 'stationLon',mode='w')
```

and get `KeyError: "None of [Index(['s', 't', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'L', 'o', 'n'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`. But I do have the column 'stationLon' in the file of `filepath_10ormore`, and I have closed the file before I run `.to_csv()`

`Lon_count` is pandas series, like below. I didn't show df2 in order to short the code, as I did run the part before the line writing `Lon_count` to csv file successfully.

**Index** **values**

1.2345 4

1.2346 2

1.2347 7

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `columns` argument expects a sequence (usually a list) of column names. You're specifying a string, so it tries to iterate that sequence, looking for columns named `"s"`, `"t"`, etc.

Try including the column name in a list, like this:

```
Lon_count.to_csv(filepath_10ormore,float_format="%.4f",columns= ['stationLon'],mode='w')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation sj95126, it really works! I also saw the edit about the question, thank you!